# How does bind-attr in ember.js work?

Tags: binding, ember.js

I haven't actually built an app yet, but I'm confused by documentation on bind-attr. It says you can do something like:

```
App.LogoView = Ember.View.extend({
  logoUrl: 'http://www.mycorp.com/images/logo.png'
});
```

With a template:

```
<div id="logo">
  <img {{bind-attr =logoUrl}} alt="Logo" />
</div>
```

To produce:

```
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://www.mycorp.com/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
</div>
```

*And Similarly:*

```
App.AlertView = Ember.View.extend({
  priority: "p4",
  isUrgent: true
});
```

With a template:

```
<div {{bind-attr =priority}}>
  Warning!
</div>
```

To produce:

```
<div class="p4">
  Warning!
</div>
```

How does Ember know it was the `src` attribute in the first example and a `class` attribute in the second example? Unless I'm missing something here, this doesn't seem like it's really even possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The documentation appears to be wrong. Running the code as listed in the docs, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Parse error on line 4:
...    <img {{bind-attr =logoUrl}} alt="Lo
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE', 'STRING', 'INTEGER', 'BOOLEAN', 'ID', 'SEP'
```

Running the code as you would *expect* it to look works fine. You need to specify the attribute in question:

```html
<div id="logo">
    <img {{bind-attr src=logoUrl}} alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/HG64E/) (remove the attribute name and look for the error in the console).

Comment: OH! yes that would make much more sense.  I wonder who I notify about documentation errors.

Comment: You could try the [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues).

Comment: The source documentation has already been fixed. The website has simply not yet been updated.

Comment: The current version of the relevant docs for this topic is available here: [Templates: Binding Element Attributes](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/)